# Most effective way to create a class that has a small variance in derived classes

Tags: c#, design-patterns, abstract-class

I have a class that contains a lot of functionality called `Record`. In the system there exist two basic types of records that have a primary key that is `uint`, and those that have a primary key of `Guid`.

The `Record` class contains all the features that I need except for one property. `Record.ID` allows the developer to read the current primary key as the correct type (`uint` or `Guid`).

To achieve this I had to create three classes like this (simplified example):

```
class Record {
    ... lots of code ...
}

class RecordInt : Record {
     public uint ID { get; set; }
}

class RecordGuid : Record {
     public Guid ID { get; set; }
}
```

This works ok, but it introduced a problem where data models can't just create a generic `Record` instance. They have to know if derive classes are expecting `RecordInt` or `RecordGuid`. So I added a template argument to models like this.

```
class abstract class Model<T> : were T : Record, new()
{
   ... lots of generic code that uses T ...

   // example
   public List<T> Find(...) { 
      .. find a record ...
      return new List<T>(); 
   }
}
```

This has caused me more problems than the benefit of simply having two `Record` types. Now when I instantiate a model the code has to know what type of `Record` is required. If that takes place in a section that should be generic, then I have to add another template argument.

I found after a while there started to be a lot of methods using template arguments. Just so that type could be passed to `Model<RecordGuid>`, and sometimes I have to pass the template argument down a chain of several method calls befor it gets to code that really needs it.

Is there a more effective pattern then what I'm doing?

**EDIT:**

One reason why `Model` is using a template argument is that it needs to have methods that return collections of `Record`. In C# you can't cast `List<Record>` to `List<RecordGuid>` so I had to use a template argument for the return type as `List<T>`.

Comment: I'm not sure what the title of this question should be.

Comment: The only differece between them is the ID property type?

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos, Yes the type for the ID.

Comment: Could you pass to the model a factory method that returns `Record` objects but which really creates ones of the required derived type?

Comment: @MatthewWatson That could work.

Comment: Type traits for C# perhaps? http://stackoverflow.com/q/10729230/2065121

Comment: @MatthewWatson, a factory doesn't work if I want methods to return a collection of `List<RecordGuid>`. I can't cast from `List<Record>` to `List<RecordGuid>`.

Comment: @RogerRowland, interesting idea. Could you expand that as an answer? How might I implement it?

Comment: What I've done before is to have `class Record<TId> { TId Id; }` with the model/repository having `Record<TId> Find<TId>(TId id) { ... }` You could have your `Record<TId>` inheriting from a `Record` class for the extra functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I decided to create a new class to represent primary keys, and have that class control the `Type` state for that ID.

This would allow me to create just a single class to represent a `Record` while that class could support either `uint` or `Guid` primary keys. It also means that the `Model` class no longer required template arguments which resulted in other source code dependant upon `Model` to also not require template arguments.

Here is my `PrimaryValue` class that I'm using.

```
/// <summary>
/// Used to store the value of the primary key for a table.
/// </summary>
public sealed class PrimaryValue
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The raw value
    /// </summary>
    private object _value;

    /// <summary>
    /// The required type.
    /// </summary>
    private Type _type;

    /// <summary>
    /// True if a Guid type.
    /// </summary>
    public bool IsGUID
    {
        get
        {
            return _type == typeof(Guid);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Type if a uint type.
    /// </summary>
    public bool IsInteger
    {
        get
        {
            return _type == typeof(uint);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// True if the value is empty.
    /// </summary>
    public bool Empty
    {
        get
        {
            if (_type == typeof(uint))
            {
                return (uint)_value == 0;
            }
            return (Guid)_value == Guid.Empty;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor
    /// </summary>
    public PrimaryValue(Type pType)
    {
        _type = pType;
        if (pType == typeof(uint))
        {
            _value = 0;
        }
        else if (pType == typeof(Guid))
        {
            _value = Guid.Empty;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ModelException("Type not supported by PrimaryValue.");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// UINT constructor.
    /// </summary>
    public PrimaryValue(uint pValue)
    {
        _value = pValue;
        _type = typeof(uint);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// GUID constructor
    /// </summary>
    public PrimaryValue(Guid pValue)
    {
        _value = pValue;
        _type = typeof(Guid);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Copy constructor.
    /// </summary>
    public PrimaryValue(PrimaryValue pValue)
    {
        _value = pValue._value;
        _type = pValue._type;
    }

    public void set(PrimaryValue pValue)
    {
        if (_type == pValue._type)
        {
            _value = pValue._value;
            return;
        }

        throw new ModelException("PrimaryValues are not of the same type.");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Assigns a UINT value.
    /// </summary>
    public void set(uint pValue)
    {
        if (_type == typeof(uint))
        {
            _value = pValue;
            return;
        }

        throw new ModelException("PrimaryValue is not a UINT type.");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Assigns a GUID value.
    /// </summary>
    public void set(Guid pValue)
    {
        if (_type == typeof(Guid))
        {
            _value = pValue;
            return;
        }

        throw new ModelException("PrimaryValue is not a GUID type.");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the raw value.
    /// </summary>
    public object get()
    {
        return _value;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the ID as UINT.
    /// </summary>
    public uint ToInteger()
    {
        if (_type != typeof(uint))
        {
            throw new ModelException("PrimaryValue is not a UINT type.");
        }
        return (uint)_value;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the ID as GUID.
    /// </summary>
    public Guid ToGuid()
    {
        if (_type != typeof(Guid))
        {
            throw new ModelException("PrimaryValue is not a GUID type.");
        }
        return (Guid)_value;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Checks if two IDs are equal.
    /// </summary>
    public static bool operator ==(PrimaryValue A, PrimaryValue B)
    {
        if (A._value.GetType() == B._value.GetType())
        {
            return A._value == B._value;
        }

        throw new ModelException("Can not compare PrimaryValues of different types.");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Checks if two IDs are not equal.
    /// </summary>
    public static bool operator !=(PrimaryValue A, PrimaryValue B)
    {
        if (A._value.GetType() == B._value.GetType())
        {
            return A._value != B._value;
        }

        throw new ModelException("Can not compare PrimaryValues of different types.");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Convertion to UINT.
    /// </summary>
    public static implicit operator uint(PrimaryValue A)
    {
        return A.ToInteger();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Convertion to Guid.
    /// </summary>
    public static implicit operator Guid(PrimaryValue A)
    {
        return A.ToGuid();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Convertion to string.
    /// </summary>
    public static implicit operator string(PrimaryValue A)
    {
        return A._value.ToString();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Convert to string.
    /// </summary>
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return _value.ToString();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Hashcode
    /// </summary>
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return _value.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```