# C++ - Put members in common for two sub classes

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

Let a library containing the following class hierarchy :

```
class LuaChunk
{
};

class LuaExpr : public LuaChunk
{
};

class LuaScript : public LuaChunk
{
};
```

Now I would like to use this library in my application by extending these two classes :

```
class AppLuaExpr : public LuaExpr
{
private:

    Foo * someAppSpecificMemberFoo;
    Bar * someAppSpecificMemberBar;
};

class AppLuaScript : public LuaScript
{
private:

    Foo * someAppSpecificMemberFoo;
    Bar * someAppSpecificMemberBar;
};
```

The problem here is that, if I have many members, each of them having its own pair of getter/setter, it's going to generate a lot of code duplication.

Is there a way, that does not use multiple inheritance (which I want to avoid) to put in common the application-specific stuff contained in both `AppLuaExpr` and `AppLuaExpr` ?

I've taken a look on the existing structural design patterns listed on Wikipedia, but it doesn't seem like any f these is adapted to my issue.

Thank you.

Comment: How about using *composition* ? Create a class with your common members and code, and add it as a member of your concrete classes ?

Comment: @Louen Thanks for your help. Yes that seems to be an option. Any other idea ?

Comment: @songyuanyao No I can't do that. As I mentionned, the first 3 classes described above are within a library which I can't add application-specific stuff to, otherwise it's no longer a library.

Comment: @Virus721 Then is it possible to make a class template? What's the difference between `AppLuaExpr` and `AppLuaScript`?

Comment: @songyuanyao Well the `AppLuaScript` class would contain extra pointers to components of the application that can be manipulated from the script. What do you mean exactely with templates ?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid multiple inheritance? It's literally designed to solve this problem.

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet For the same reasons most other languages decided to get rid of it.

Comment: @Virus721: That's absurd.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could express the common data as their own class and pass that during construction. That way you can encapsulate everything using composition.

```
class Core { }; 

class Component { 
    int one, two;
public:
    Component(int one, int two) : one(one), two(two)
    {}
};

class Mobious : public Core 
{
    Component c;
public:
    Mobious(Component &c) : Core(), c(c) { }
};

class Widget : public Core
{
    Component c;
public:
    Widget(Component &c) : Core(), c(c)
    {}
};

int main(void)
{
    Widget w(Component{1, 2});
    Mobious m(Component{2, 3});;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I think compositing is what I'm going to use.

Comment: @Virus721 If there are dependencies that are only initialised once but used in both classes consider using a `shared_ptr` (smart pointers) to express that. This helps to ensure that a resource only is initialised and destructed once in your application.

Comment: @Virus721 For the record, this uses *composition* (delegate functionality to a class using members) along with *inversion of control* (passing the delegated-to class in a constructor).