# Traits and extension methods in C#

Tags: c#

Are C# extension methods considered as trait?

From what i read at wikipedia [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trait_(computer_programming))  a trait is a concept in OOP which represents a set of methods that can be used to extend the funcionality of a class. So the extension methods in C# do just that, don't they?

However in supported languages I cant see C# support which confuses me a lot. Do i understand the concept correctly?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10729230/how-would-you-implement-a-trait-design-pattern-in-c

Comment: *"trait is a concept in OOP which represents a set of methods that can be used to extend the functionality of a class"* - that's the beginning, continue reading. The closest thing to trait in c# is `interface` as it seems, but they can't contain implementation, nor satisfy all traits of *trait*.