# template specialization via extension method

Tags: c#

In C#, I'd like to have a method of my generic class behave in different ways, using something akin to [explicit template specialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization)

I see from [a related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600978/how-to-do-template-specialization-in-c-sharp) that such a thing might be possible in C#, using extensions, but my code is not behaving as desired: I want one behaviour for `Thing<int>::Method()` and another behaviour when `<T>` is anything other than `<int>`.

I have

```
using System;

public interface IThing
{
    void Method();
}

public class Thing<T> : IThing
{
    public void Method() 
    {
        this.Specialization<T>();
    }
}

public static class ThingExtensions
{
    public static void Specialization<T>(this Thing<T> cls)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Thing<T> specialization");
        return;
    }

    public static void Specialization(this Thing<int> cls)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Thing<int> specialization");
        return;
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var t = new Thing<float>();
        t.Method();
        t.Specialization();

        var i = new Thing<int>();
        i.Method();
        i.Specialization();
    }
}
```

But this outputs

```
Thing<T> specialization
Thing<T> specialization
Thing<T> specialization
Thing<int> specialization
```

Rather than

```
Thing<T> specialization
Thing<T> specialization
Thing<int> specialization
Thing<int> specialization
```

The obvious question "why not just call `Specialization<T>` rather than `Method`?" is hopefully answered by my inclusion of the interface class - I am trying to fit into *its* framework.

I can see that `Specialization<T>` is a match for `Specialization<int>`, but I'm surprised that the latter is not regarded as a better match!

Comment: If your only concern is type int, why not just use one specialization method of type <T> and check the type before performing your logic?

Comment: Generics aren't templates. What you are asking sounds like traits anyway, not template specialization. The clean solution is coming in C# 8 with [default interface implementations](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/288). I posted an example in [a related question last week](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10729230/how-would-you-implement-a-trait-design-pattern-in-c/53450332#53450332)

Comment: Overload resolution happens at *compile time*. When `Method` is being *compiled*, what type information does it have to hand, and so which `Specialization` overload is it going to choose?

Comment: The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10729336/134204) in the traits question shows how to work with "traits" without official support - different traits have to implemented using extension methods that target different interfaces, one per "trait". They'll have to be called through that interface too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, when you call `Method()` it is running as `Thing<T>`, not knowing it is `Thing<int>`. You can use reflection to find this out, or (better idea):

```
if(this instanceof Thing<int> x)
  x.Specialisation();
else
  this.Specialisation();
```

Alternatively you can declare `Method()` as `virtual` and create `IntThing : Thing<int>` with `override void Method(){...}`

Answer (score 1):

The call to `this.Specialization<T>();` is resolved when the containing method is compiled. At that point `T` is anything.

Some languages with generic support (eg. C++) resolve the implementation of generic methods as late as possible, when all type parameters (or in C++'s case all template parameters: in C++ template parameters are not restricted to types).

But C# does not take this approach. This does have the advantage of making the compilation model simpler, but it is less powerful.

(Personally I would like the ability to explicitly specialise, including partial specialisation, but I also recognise this has challenges for the way types are resolved in .NET.)